# StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following problem with my Selenium in Java. It generates the error, that the element is no longer attached to the DOM (`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException`). I found some solutions to wait, but they did not work (wait.driver, Thread.sleep).

I have tried by below code but it is not working:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath1)));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).sendKeys("A");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath2)));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).sendKeys("B");
```

How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java? Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: For which element do you get that exception?

Comment: Sometime first line, sometime 4th line.

Comment: Please post your HTML in the question and properly format it. It will make it easier to find and read.

Comment: Here: [link](http://pastebin.com/njhx6kmX)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve, but it is not too pretty solution:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath1)));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).clear();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).sendKeys("A");
Thread.sleep(1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath2)));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).clear();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).sendKeys("B");
```

I think the Page is slow, maybe operations of the database are slow or something similar to these.